# Using logic in your update methods

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm working on a little game with some fellow students and I'm wanting some guidance on how to handle the problem...

With my code what it boils down to is I want to call into use  the Boss_Shoot Class where  the Boss class update() starts printing "should be shooting"  ..  the print statement statements seen through out are nothing more then a "placeholder of sorts...

As always Thanks so much!

```
class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/boss.png")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.dx = 1
    self.dy = 1
    self.shoot= True

 def update(self):

    if self.rect.centerx >= 600:
        self.rect.centerx -= self.dx
    elif self.rect.centerx <= 600:

        print "should be shooting"
    self.rect.centery -= self.dy
    self.checkBounds()

def checkBounds(self):
    if self.rect.top <= 0:
        self.dy *= -1
        print 
    if self.rect.bottom >= 500:
        self.dy *= -1

class Boss_Shoot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (320, 240)
        self.dy =2

    def update(self):
        if self.shoot == True:
            print "shooting"
        for i in range(100):   
            print "wtf man"
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(1000, 3000)
            self.rect.y = random. randrange(10, 490)
            self.rect.x -= 5
            self.rect.y +=self.dy
```

Comment: `I have seen weird thing happen` be specific please. It's a waste of time if we have to try and figure out what 'might' be going wrong while you already know

Comment: I was speaking in generalities..  sorry..  with my particular code I want to call the ShootBoss class as a constructor statement in my Boss Class and replace the print statement "should be shooting" with that constructor.

Comment: I want to use boss_shoot =bossShoot.update() but its not working..  so I try to create the constructor bossShot = Boss_Shoot() but that doesn't work either

Comment: finally I didn't get an error with Boss_Shoot.update or Boss_Shoot.__init__ but its not working ..so I guess I have bigger problems

Answer (score 1):

You need a way your actors (or Sprites, or whatever you call your "entities") can communicate with the global state of your game.

You didn't show all your code, so I assume everything is in one file.

Somewhere in your code, you probably have a list of all actors (and if you don't, you should create one). Let's assume it's defined as:

```
actors = []
```

Maybe you use a single list, maybe you want to use pygame's `Group` class.

I further assume you call the `update()` method on all actors in your mainloop, like:

```
for a in actors:
    a.update()
```

(or, if you use pygame's `Group` class, something like `mygroup.update()`).

Now, in the `update()` method of `Boss`, just create a new instance of `Boss_Shoot`, and add it to the list of actors, like:

```
def update(self):
    if self.rect.centerx >= 600:
        self.rect.centerx -= self.dx
    elif self.rect.centerx <= 600:
        actors.append(Boss_Shoot())
```

You probably want to pass the position of `Boss` to the `Boss_Shoot` constructor so the bullet (or whatever) doesn't randomly appear on the screen (if you want to).

---

I prefer encapsulating the gamestate into a seperate `dict` or `class`, and pass that down to each actor so each actor can register/unregister itself from the world, something like:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._actors = []

    def register(self, actor):
        self._actors.append(actor)

    def unregister(self, actor):
        self._actors.remove(actor)

    def update(self):
        for a in self._actors:
            a.update()
    ...

class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
        self.state.register(self)
        ...

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.centerx >= 600:
            self.rect.centerx -= self.dx
        elif self.rect.centerx <= 600:
            self.state.register(Boss_Shoot(self.state))

class Boss_Shoot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
        self.state.register(self)
        ...

while True:
    state.update()
    state.draw(screen)
    ...
```

You'll get the idea.